# How to create a smbolic link over the internet

Tags: symlink

I would like to be able to create a symbolic link over the internet, that allows you to create a link that e.g. C:\Windows\test.txt to http://www.test.com/test.txt

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I am sure it is in some way or other..

Comment: You can map a network drive and then symbolic link using it's assigned drive ID.

Comment: doesn't windows have .url files that are .lnk files but to urls?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible to do?

No. You can create a Windows shortcut, but you can't create a symbolic link to an http site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In Windows, a shortuct can either be a `.lnk` file or a `.url` file. The former works for local files, while the latter works for URLs.

The `.lnk` format is a bit difficult to work with manually, but for the sake of your question, you don't need it.
The `.url` format, on the other hand, is just a plain text file. Example:

```
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://google.com/
IDList=
HotKey=0
IconFile=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
IconIndex=4
```

To be honest, I don't know what the first two lines are for, but the shortcut still works without them.

You can even generate this file manually.